# kernel: [258605.922058] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.2.107 Send error in SessSetup = -11 after upgrade to 20.04.1

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

hope I can get some help. I have to be honest up-front, I do not have great linux skills - still learning.
I recently upgraded to 20.04.1. I don't know if these errors started right after that, or after something else I had done.

`kernel: [258605.922058] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.2.107 Send error in SessSetup = -11`

I've tried searching for what -11 means, but I can't seem to find what this error is indicating. I know these errors weren't there prior to 20.04.1 LTS upgrade.

This is the statements for my fstab mounts: I've been tweaking them quite a bit last few days trying to resolve the error...

```
//192.168.2.107/Multimedia/New /home/New/ cifs credentials=/etc/.kreditiv3,_netdev,vers=2.0,nobrl,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//192.168.2.107/Multimedia/Parents /home/Multimedia/Parents/ cifs credentials=/etc/.kreditiv3,_netdev,vers=2.0,nobrl,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//192.168.2.94/video/Movies /home/movies/Movies cifs credentials=/etc/.kreditiv1,_netdev,vers=2.0,nobrl,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//192.168.2.107/calibre/ /home/calibre-library cifs nobrl,credentials=/etc/.kreditiv3,uid=rob,gid=family,_netdev,vers=2.0,nobrl,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp 0 0
//192.168.2.27/movies /home/movies/oldies cifs users,credentials=/etc/.kreditiv2,uid=root,gid=root,_netdev,vers=1.0,nobrl,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//192.168.2.94/NetBackup /home/backup cifs credentials=/etc/.kreditiv1,_netdev,vers=2.0,nobrl,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//192.168.2.94/Audiobooks /home/audiobooks cifs credentials=/etc/.kreditiv1,_netdev,vers=2.0,nobrl,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Everything seems to actually work, except for the fact I'm getting lots of errors. It seems to give the error a couple of times every hour, but I don't know why, or which mount. Without disabling a mount for a few hours, and breaking my applications (sonarr/radarr/plex/calibre), is there something I can check?
The mounts are physically on external raid boxes (qnap and synology devices).

Comment: What kind of server system is there at IPv4 address 192.168.2.107? Does it report any problems in its log?

Comment: It is a Qnap 2-bay raid box model TAS-268. No errors in the logs at all.

Comment: Hm, strange. That sort of error messages usually stems from server side errors. Ok, I'm out.

Comment: I may have fixed it. I removed the nobrl from the fstab entry. I read that when this is on, if you are transferring large values of data, the oplocking can cause timeouts to the remote mount. I've removed that entry in the fstab for the .107 IP, and i haven't had the error now for over 5 hours. (normally it was several an hour).

Comment: No, still getting the errors, but less frequently now. I haven't been able to find a list of what all the error codes mean

Comment: The message is emitted by the kernel. The numeric error code it reports is a Linux errno value. Possible errno values can be found in the kernel source file include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h. -11 is -EAGAIN which means simply "Try again". But that doesn't really help here. The big question (for which I do not know the answer) is why (under which circumstances) the kernel emits that message instead of simply doing what the code says, ie. trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting this answer from your Reddit post in case folks find this one first.

Adding `echo_interval=30` to my fstab options for each mount seems to have gotten rid of the messages.

eg.

`//qnap/mp3-albums /mp3/mp3-albums cifs echo_interval=30,vers=3.0,credentials=/root/cifsuser,rw 0 0`